# Image position using safari driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to make a screen capture of a web page and then retrieve the size and location of an image and finaly save the image in a file.

Snippet:

```
this.driver.navigate().to(xxx);

final byte[] arrScreen = ((TakesScreenshot) this.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
final BufferedImage imageScreen = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(arrScreen));
final WebElement cap = this.driver.findElement(By.id("myImageId"));

final Dimension capDimension = cap.getSize();
final Point capLocation = cap.getLocation();
final BufferedImage imgCap = imageScreen.getSubimage(capLocation.x, capLocation.y,
            capDimension.width, capDimension.height);

final File file = new File(".../capture.png");
final FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
ImageIO.write(imgCap, "png", os);
```

This work fine using windows os (ChromeDriver) but it doesn't work (the coordinates are wrong) using mac os (ChromeDriver and SafariDriver both fail).

Any idea why ?

**Edit:**

Is there any difference between `TakesScreenshot` in Windows and Mac os ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this :

```
final BufferedImage imgCap = imageScreen.getSubimage(capLocation.x, capLocation.y,
        capDimension.width, capDimension.height);
```

with this and it works well :

```
final BufferedImage imgCap = imageScreen.getSubimage(capLocation.x * 2, capLocation.y * 2,
        capDimension.width * 2, capDimension.height * 2);
```

but i still don't know why, any idea ?